Appropriate Test for Measuring Change in Event Occurrence Over Time (RStudio)
I want to see if a training programme delivered to organisations to reduce the rate at which an event occurs actually has the intended effect of reducing said occurrence.
Each organisation that is part of the study (theoretically) has as many members of the organisation as possible take a survey that asks them to self-report their experiences as a rating from 1 to 5. I say theoretically because not all organisations took the survey every year, so some might do it for the first 2 years, not do it in the 3rd year, but then do it again in the 4th year, which may also need to be considered when picking a statistical test. For each organisation, a mean is calculated for what percentage of people within that organisation gave a rating of 4 or 5.
I've then grouped the organisations in RStudio to get mean percentages across different calendar years (e.g. 2015, 2016, 2017), years from registration date (1st year registered, 2nd, 3rd, etc.), and survey number (first, second, third time taking the survey regardless of if they took breaks between years, etc.).
I'm now looking to analyse these means and see if these different groups show decreases in the mean percentage over time, but I'm not sure what the most appropriate way to do this is. I've included some example plots I've made:

The most obvious way would be to do some sort of correlation/linear regression analysis, but because the survey number isn't fully independent since it's sequential I'm not sure if that'd be the correct thing to do?
I know there's the potential to do something like a paired/repeated measures ANOVA type thing but I've only seen that done for a maximum of 3 time measures whereas I have at least 7 time points so I'm not sure if there's a hard number limit on that or not. I also don't have multiple groups to compare the means of, it's just year on year change - However because not all organisations took the survey every year they were registered so I don't know if I should also do some kind of Registered Year*Survey Number ANOVA comparison to account for that.
